# Can I use a calculated query string in a spatial index query?

Tags: cypher, neo4j-spatial

I have a set of nodes labeled 'Foo' with associated geographic information, and for each node in that set I want to find nodes from a second set that are geographically nearby. The nodes in the second set have been added to a spatial index named 'tree'. I have tried to construct a query along the lines of

```
MATCH (n:Foo)
WITH n, 'withinDistance:[' + n.lat + ',' + n.lon + ',10.0]' as q
START m = node:tree(q)
RETURN n, m LIMIT 2
```

but I get the error

> Invalid input ')': expected an identifier character, whitespace or '='

This error is associated with the last character in line 3.

Is it possible to use a constructed query string? If so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So, Michael Hunger provided the answer. This is a constraint in Cypher. Unfortunate, but there it is. You cannot do what I was trying to do. The spatial index query string must be a string literal or a parameter passed in via REST.

Comment: That is the answer. You can't use a constructed query string, and it is a constraint in Cypher.